# Are the camera and display connectors of my 3B+ soldered the wrong way around?

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, connectors

I recently purchased a new 3B+ board and although the board board itself is working fine, I can't get the PiNoir camera to work.
The camera works fine on an another 3B board.
I tried several tricks on software level (raspi-config, v4l2 driver,...) and checked several times that the hardware connection is correct.

What triggered me is that I switched the orientation of the ribbon cable on purpose and this resulted in a short-circuit / faulty voltages. This surprised me, as the connector is apparently connecting only one side of the ribbon.

I then compared my board with official pictures. It looks like my board has the camera and display connectors soldered the wrong way around.

**Are the camera and display connectors soldered the wrong way around, or do I simply have connectors with an alternative mechanical design?**

My raspi 3B+:
[image: My raspi 3B+]

Official image from the raspi foundation:
[image: Official image from the raspi foundation]

Comment: mine looks a little different to the official - but wow! that is ODD (I'm sure they'd still work though) - what is the output of `grep Revision /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I've just looked at all 8 of my Pi's - (models 1b/2b/3b/3b+) and the orientation of the plastic in those headers all look more like the official pic than yours. That's so weird! (yes, I have 8 pi's ... I have a problem :p, or an octo-pi)

Comment: @JaromandaX : the output of `grep Revision /proc/cpuinfo` is `Revision : a020d3`.

Comment: Ok. So there isn't a new revision

Comment: I wonder if you reported this to the Foundation and got any feedback that would make a good answer here?

Comment: They certainly look to be rotated, if you can find a 15-way FFC with "same sided" contacts to use then your camera should work, the usual ribbon has contacts on opposite sides. For example https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/cable-wire-cable-assemblies/cable-assemblies/ffc-fpc-flat-flex-jumper-cables?contact-orientation=same-sided-contacts&st=15core